# add element after all DIV tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I wan't add element after every DIV tag, while 'i=0','i=1','i=2'...untill 'max-DIV.length'. What should I do? I'm just a little worry.. OH!

```js
var NewSpan = document.createElement("span");
NewSpan.setAttribute("id", "gotop");
var NewSpanText = document.createTextNode("to be continue...");
NewSpan.appendChild(NewSpanText);

var i = 0;

var OldDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];
var parent = OldDiv.parentNode;
if (parent.lastChild == OldDiv) {
  parent.appendChild(NewSpan);
} else {
  parent.insertBefore(NewSpan, OldDiv.nextSibling);
};
```

```html
<div id="n1">DIV</div>
<div id="n2">DIV</div>
<div id="n3">DIV</div>
<div id="n4">DIV</div>
```

[lile this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xqJL.png)

Comment: You're looking for a [`for` loop.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: I tried it ,but it just created one elememt, not every div tag

Comment: Did you create a new `span` during the loop?

Comment: only one <span> be created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap this in a `for` loop and create a new `span` element every time you want to insert one.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var NewSpan = document.createElement("span");
  NewSpan.setAttribute("id", "gotop" + i); // Can't have duplicate IDs
  var NewSpanText = document.createTextNode("to be continue...");
  NewSpan.appendChild(NewSpanText);
  var OldDiv = divs[i];
  var parent = OldDiv.parentNode;
  if (parent.lastChild == OldDiv) {
    parent.appendChild(NewSpan);
  } else {
    parent.insertBefore(NewSpan, OldDiv.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="n1">DIV</div>
<div id="n2">DIV</div>
<div id="n3">DIV</div>
<div id="n4">DIV</div>
```

Comment: _NewSpan.setAttribute("id", "gotop" + i);_ should be **NewSpan.setAttribute("id", "gotop") + i;**

Comment: @Ching No it shouldn't. I'm modifying the ID because you can't have the same ID attached to multiple elements.